# How much faster is mysqli over fopen?

Tags: php, mysqli, fopen

I am just making a very basic cms for making a one page website.
The php would not be accessed from general users. Rather, it is only there to generate the html site.
I may however use the code for general users if probable.

For certain reasons using databases would cause a few problems so I am considering using fopen.
How does fopen compare to mysqli? I just want an idea of at what stage does using fopen become much more of a burden.

Thanks

Comment: fopen is mainly used to open up a file on the web server. mysqli is a database API -- if you have the thought to not use a database but rather store your user information in a text file.. I would reconsider this straight away

Comment: use a db not a flat file, the former is designed for this, the latter is not.

Comment: Cms stored in a file. Good luck on your journey.

Comment: side note speed should never be the only consideration, many 'speed' saving ideas cost more in other ways. with modern hardware ease of maintenance is worth a lot more (human time is far more expensive than adding another cpu or some ram) than a few milliseconds of speed.

Comment: Use a database - any that fits the use-case. It  *won't* be/cause "a few problems".

Comment: Thanks, no there would be no user information in the file.
I can't see how a small cms in a file wouldn't work. It is not like I am making Joomla or anything, just something very basic with no sensitive data.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `fopen` for what? And what problems with MySQL?

Anyway, the two are incomparable:

`fopen` is a function opens a file on disk and `mysqli` is a set of functions for working with MySQL databases.

`fopen` is not safe for use in simultaneous requests - if the same script is ran twice simultaneously (e.g. two people making the same GET request within miliseconds of each other) then corruption will occur if one of the scripts writes to the file, so you'll have to use a locking file, which will make performance suffer.

Using MySQL (version 5+) gives you an ACID-compliant data storage solution.

If it's a "one-page website" as you say then you might get away with using `fopen`, just be sure to use locking-files appropriate (as well as good security!).

Comment: If it was possible to give more up votes.. You'd get it

Comment: Thanks for the great answer.
No, there are no problems with MySQL, it is more a company department issue. Setting up databases etc. might be tricky so I was considering an alternative.
The system would only be used by a few people and so would involve no sensitive data.
The simultaneous request information is very valuable, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Looking into CMS's like WordPress, Drupal or Joomla would be a better option as compared to have it on file system, although I would like to point out that those CMS's are capable for more than just serving static pages. I am not sure what kind of data you hope to store in the File but you will have to encounter at least two major issues with it, `integrity` and `locking`. And still `it's very hard for me to imagine how that might not create an unpleasant experience for a user especially with concurrency and locking ?`

I am not aware of any "`reasons using databases would cause a few problems`". Mysqli is an object oriented driver for Mysql that also allows things that mysql driver for php doesn't.

But yes, having a Database does impose certain security liabilities, but by a good programming practice and following an accepted paradigm it's not that hard a problem to rule out. And IMO this is a kind of problem that arises from the control we have over the DB. So many inexperienced developers have publicized this.

If you are considering a career out of web development looking into MVC frameworks might also be a good idea. These frameworks have most of the boiler plate codes in them and some of them force you to follow a good practice making your applications scalable, robust and secure.

For me though, having it on a flat file system is a no, no, no ... ;)